# Oracle: What is the data type of ORA_ROWSCN?

Tags: oracle

What is the data type of ORA_ROWSCN?  It *seems* to be NUMBER but I cannot find it specified in the documentation.

```
declare
  myscn  ???;
begin
    select ora_rowscn into myscn from t where ...;
end;
```

Comment: It is specified in [the documentation for the function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions142.htm) `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP()`, which accepts a `NUMBER` as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a `NUMBER`.  You can see yourself by creating a simple view and describing it (or selecting from `*_tab_columns`).  Here's a simple [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49823/1) demonstration

```
create table foo (
   col1 number
);

create view vw_foo
as
select col1, ora_rowscn scn
  from foo;

select * 
  from user_tab_cols 
 where table_name = 'VW_FOO';
```

If you want more detail than you'd probably ever care about on the format of the SCN (system change number), here is [one decent article](https://orainternals.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/scn-what-why-and-how/)